# How does the weather compare between Bali and Vietnam in April?

Tags: weather-and-climate, vietnam, bali

I want to go to Vietnam or Bali in this April with friends, but our decision will be largely based on the suitability of the weather that month.  How does the weather differ between those two places during this time of year?

I can stay only 5 days. My current residence is Singapore.

Comment: By "suitable and good", do you mean the weather?  If yes, please clarify your question, or this is likely to get closed as too vague/opinion-based.

Comment: According to weather which place is suitable to visit in April?

Comment: Your original question was almost bordering on subjective, and it depends on your choice - some like cooler weather, some prefer it stinking hot (see [help] on why subjective questions are off topic).  I've rewritten your question to be more on topic, I hope that's ok, please edit/update if anything's missing.

Comment: Also, what part of Bali / Vietnam? Both have quite different areas -  beaches, low lands and mountains...

Comment: Hope to go to beach side.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on where in Vietnam you are thinking about in terms of north and south, not mountains or beach.

The southern and central parts of Vietnam will be quite hot in April (hottest time of year, avg temps in the mid 30s), while the northern reaches around Hanoi are still cooler (avg temps in the low 20s, their hottest time is June - Aug).  April is still dry season in all areas.

Bali doesn't change a whole lot in terms of temperature between summer and winter (28 to 31 similar to Singapore), mostly in terms of how long it rains (dry season has short showers, rainy season has long downpours).

So in the long run, not a huge difference between them weather wise.